# Item's title - invalid characters

Tags: error, item

is there a SP function that returns a valid title string for item? For example, I get an error for 0x07 (bullet) character, and from time to time I discover some new character that is not valid. I'm programatically setting title. So, which characters are valid and which invalid for item's title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a ton of guidance out there on the invalid characters topic around SharePoint, I have never seen any that speaks specifically to list item titles.  It's mostly related to site, doclib/list, folder, and file names to make sure you don't run into any problems with URLs...here's KB article from Msft on the subject:

[Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names--fo) | Microsoft Support

I think from human-readability and co-existance with 3rd party solution standpoints I would myself restrict the title to alpha-numeric characters, but you're probably OK following the guidance on filename. in the referenced KB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: broken URL, any summary?

Comment: @Bratch I've fixed the URL. ;)